# Aws IoT : How to use an application service on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-iot

I'd like to use AWS IoT to manage a grid of devices. Data by device must be sent to a queue service (RabbitMQ) hosted on an EC2 instance that is the starting point for a real time control application. I read how to make a rule to write data to other Service: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rule-actions.html)

However there isn't an example for EC2. Using the AWS IoT service, how can I connect to a service on EC2?

Edit:
I have a real time application developed with storm that consume data from RabbitMQ and puts the result of computation in another RabbitMQ queue. RabbitMQ and storm are on EC2. I have devices producing data and connected to IoT. Data produced by devices must be redirected to the queue on EC2 that is the starting point of my application.
I'm sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is confusing. Do you wish to send data to RabbitMQ, or to AWS IoT? You also referenced information about Apache Storm. If I had to guess, it would appear that you wish to send data to IoT and then have it on-send to Rabbit MQ? Could you please Edit your question to clarify the actual flow of your data from source to destination? Thank you.

Comment: I believe the reason you don't see examples of this is that AWS IoT interacts directly with other AWS services like SNS, Lambda, or Kinesis -- but only indirectly with your own services, so a custom integration would be used to send collected data into custom destinations... for example, a Lambda function you develop could connect to your RabbitMQ and pass these messages.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks, so there is no way to connect IoT and EC2 and I must use lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS IoT supports pushing the data directly to other AWS services. As you have probably figured out by now publishing to third party APIs isn't directly supported.

From the choices AWS offers Lambda, SQS, SNS and Kinesis would probably work best for you.

- With Lambda you could directly forward the incoming message using the one of Rabbit MQs APIs.
- With SQS you would put it into an AWS queue first and than poll this queue transfering it to RabbitMQ.
- Kinesis would allow more sophisticated processing, but is probably too complex.

I suggest you program a Lamba with the programming language of your choice using one of the numerous RabbitMQ APIs.